# Angular 2 (RC6) - Routing in the startup component doesn'n work

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-rc5

In my real world application I want to check in the startup component (usually app.component.ts) if a user is authenticated. If not, I want to route them to the login component. But routing doesn't work here.

I create a simple Plunker example, where it is reproduceable:

1. Open [live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/gAZ6xM?p=preview)
2. Click the button "navigate to sample 1" --> everything works
3. But you can see, that I have the same routing command already in the `app/app.component.ts` - but the application doesn't route to the component. Why??

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap it with `setTimeout()` it's working fine

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.router.navigate(["/sample1", "2"]);
});
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/5KArNd?p=preview)

It seems the default routing takes place after your call to `router.navigate()` and therefore doesn't take effect.

I'm sure there are better ways to achieve the same instead of `setTimout()` but I think it's fine to demonstrate the issue.

For example this would result in the same behavior

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: "", redirectTo: '/sample1/2', pathMatch: 'full' }
  { path: "sample1/:param1", component: Sample1Component },
  { path: "**", component: HomeComponent }
])
```

You can also use a `canActivate` guard for the default route and do the `router.navigate()` there.

Comment: You were too fast Günter I was about to write the exact same thing :) Nice post

Comment: Sorry ;-) I posted already > 5000 answers. Practice creates masters. Just don't give up.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Thank you for your answer and for your tireless support! You helped me several times now!